# Creating new "relative date ranges" for payroll periods

Tags: lightning, reporting, dashboard

My company splits each month into two payroll periods: the 1st-15th and the 16th through the end of the month (could be 28,29,30, or 31 depending on the month).

For reports and dashboards I'd like to be able to set up relative date filters for "current payroll period" and "last payroll period"... is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing... Making a Custom Field.

There are four "statuses" for Events, using the ActivityDate standard field. Four statuses are Current (meaning the event is in the current active pay period); Previous (meaning it's in the pay period before); Past (meaning it's any time before the previous pay period); and Future (meaning it's in the future).

```
IF(
  OR(
    AND(
      DAY(ActivityDate) < 16,
      DAY(TODAY()) > 15,
      YEAR(ActivityDate) = YEAR(TODAY()),
      MONTH(ActivityDate) = MONTH(TODAY())
    ),
    AND(
      DAY(ActivityDate) > 15,
      DAY(TODAY()) < 16,
      DATE(YEAR(ADDMONTHS(ActivityDate,1)),MONTH(ADDMONTHS(ActivityDate,1)),1) = 
      DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)
    )
  ),
  "Previous",
  IF(
    OR(
      AND(
        DAY(ActivityDate) < 16,
        DAY(TODAY()) < 16,
        TEXT(YEAR(ActivityDate)) = TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())),
        TEXT(MONTH(ActivityDate)) = TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
      ),
      AND(
        DAY(ActivityDate) > 15,
        DAY(TODAY()) > 15,
        TEXT(YEAR(ActivityDate)) = TEXT(YEAR(TODAY())),
        TEXT(MONTH(ActivityDate)) = TEXT(MONTH(TODAY()))
      )
    ),
    "Current",
    IF(
      ActivityDate < TODAY(), 
      "Past", 
      "Future"
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Wow! +1 for coming back *over 2-1/2 years later* to give your solution. Wish I could give you at least a +1 for each year.

Comment: Thanks, Moonpie! Your comment really made my day.